# dired copy files without overwriting?

Tags: dired

**Q:** how do I use `dired` to copy/move files without overwriting?

I'd like to use `dired` to copy (or move) files from directory *A*
to directory *B*.  However, I only want to copy files in *A* that
do not already exist in *B*.

Example:

- Directory *A* contains `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`.
- Directory *B* contains `file1.txt`.

How do I tell `dired` to copy *only* `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`
from directory *A* to directory *B*?  I can tell which ones to
mark with just a few files, but I'm thinking about situations in
which there are potentially thousands of files in the two
directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dired should prompt the user before overwriting any files by default.

Try this:

1. Create directories `A` and `B` and populate them as per your example.
2. Mark all files in directory `A` using `dired-mark-subdir-files` (default binding `* s`).
3. Copy them to directory `B` using `dired-do-copy` (default binding `C`).
4. Dired should prompt you with something like `Overwrite 'B/file1.txt'? [Type yn!q or C-h]`.
5. If you type `C-h`, Dired will explain that you can either overwrite/skip this and/or all following conflicts using the different options. In your case, `ESC` or `q` will only copy non-conflicting files.
6. Dired should report something like `Copy failed for 1 of 3 files--type ? for details ((file1.txt))`.

Comment: You may also be interested in the documentation/implementation of dired-create-files, which is where the magic happens. At its core, this function effectively wraps the core functions copy-file and rename-file, which see.